# How to Mirror one more disk on existing filesystem

Tags: lvm, mirror, hp-ux

In my test machine I can see the filesystem list using bdf commands.

```
$bdf  
Filesystem           kbytes    used   avail  %used  Mounted on  
/dev/vg00/lvol3    58916864 6242747 49386840   11%  /  
/dev/vg00/lvol1     2003481   47996  1755136    3%  /stand  
/dev/vg77/stds      5120000   18753  4782427    0%  /var/opt/stdenv  
/dev/vg77/scrap     3584000   18684  3342490    1%  /tms/vts  
/dev/vg77/cmdsscrap 3584000  530986  2862264   16%  /mnt
```

I have a scenario where I have to test the sar(1m) command to check the disk activity.
for that I need a filesystem which is mirrored and configured with more then one disk.

But unfortunately the above existing filesystems are having only one disk mirrored with it.

```
# lvdisplay -v /dev/vg00/lvol1
--- Logical volumes ---
LV Name                     /dev/vg00/lvol1
VG Name                     /dev/vg00
LV Permission               read/write                
LV Status                   available/syncd           
Mirror copies               0            
Consistency Recovery        MWC                 
Schedule                    parallel      
LV Size (Mbytes)            2000            
Current LE                  125       
Allocated PE                125         
Stripes                     0       
Stripe Size (Kbytes)        0                   
Bad block                   off          
Allocation                  strict/contiguous         
IO Timeout (Seconds)        default             

--- Distribution of logical volume ---
PV Name                 LE on PV  PE on PV  
/dev/disk/disk4         125       125  <-- Only one disk is mirrored.
```

Can anyone please let me know, How to add another disk into these existing filesystem?
Please help me with the steps for mirroring the disk with filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

Steps 
Add your extra disk and make sure the OS can see it.

Create a PV with the new disk

```
pvcreate /dev/<new device>
```

add the PV to the Volume Group

```
vgextend vg00 /dev/<new device>
```

Attache the Volume group PV to the mirror

```
lvconvert -m 1  vg00/stand  -m 1
```